# How do I get all the numbers within a range JAVA?

Tags: java, range

I have a database with a field called numberRange which is not a primary key.

Now in Java, how do I get all the numbers in the range 101000001 - 10100050?

I want to display it to display, 10100001, 101000002, 101000003, 101000004, ... 10100050.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here, I am really struggling at the moment.

Edit, database looks like this

StockID|StockName|StockPrice|StockLevels

---

1  | Water| £0.50 | 101000001 - 10100050

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loop?

Comment: You can do that using a SQL query and Resultset

Comment: @AakashGoyal, Yes, how do you do that exactly? I tried everything, and still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 is officially out.

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(101000001, 10100050);
```

Comment: ... which does not mean it should automatically be used. Do the simplest thing that works, which sounds like a for loop in this case.

Comment: @immibis Why doesn't this look like simplest thing? If it wasn't, it wouldn't have been added in Java 8.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using streams, but don't assume they're the best solution to every problem. In this case this is more concise than a for loop, more complex than a for loop (as in: you need more knowledge before you can fully understand it, even though the method name gives you a good idea of what it does). Also it's useless for anyone not using Java 8.

Comment: @RohitJain which did you learn about first - for loops or streams?

Comment: @immibis What if Rohit (among many others, myself included) was forced to first learn the hard way? Because that's my experience with imperative vs. FP-style.

Comment: @immibis You should not take this answer as being only used by OP. Might be helpful for many others. It's always good to learn new ways, specially it is a part of standard JDK.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I assumed people mainly do imperative object-oriented programming in Java, just like I assumed people mainly do functional programming in Haskell. Maybe I was wrong here.

Comment: @immibis Your comment has nothing to do with the complexity of solutions, which we are discussing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(long i = 101000001; i <= 10100050; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    //do what ever you want with your number.
}
```

Comment: Hi, what happens if I don't know the start range and finish range? As I am fetching the ranges from the database, and I can't determine the range.

Comment: @user2525364 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @Simulant What happens if I don't know the numberRange? Assume, I don't have access to the database, how do I get all the numbers from say XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXX?

Comment: @user2525364: Your Question makes no sense. If you do not know the range (starting and ending point), how do you want to know which numbers are inside this unknown range to get them all??

Comment: @Simulant, thats why I am asking here... because I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(long i = 101000001; i < 10100050; i++){
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Its not finished, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The Following SQL Query Would help

```
"select distinct numberRange from tablename where numberRange>=101000001 and numberRange<=10100050 order by numberRange"
```

Comment: In the database, I have it stored as 101000001 - 10100050.
My database looks like this


StockID | StockName | StockLevels

1           Water     101000001 - 10100050

Comment: What happens if I don't know the numberRange? Assume, I don't have access to the database, how do I get all the numbers from say XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXX?

Answer (score 0):

use jdbc and "select numberRange from yourTableName where numberRange between 101000001 and 10100050"

Comment: What happens if I don't know the numberRange? Assume, I don't have access to the database, how do I get all the numbers from say XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXX?